# Python, Selenium, waiting for the text of element to change

Tags: python, selenium

As part of my automation tests, I need to monitor changes of the `text` of an element. Changes may occur in intervals of 1 to 10 seconds. Right now, I simply check the `text` property in a loop:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

selenium_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
selenium_driver.get(url)

previous_value = None
while True:
    current_value = selenium_driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Cval")
    if previous_value:
        if (current_value.text != previous_value):
            #a new value is present.
            print("new value :", current_value.text)
            previous_value = current_value.text
    else:
        #first time running the loop.
        print("new value :", current_value.text)
        previous_value = current_value.text

    time.sleep(1) #wait 1 second before checking again.
```

I wonder if there is any better/different way to achieve this (for example telling selenium to signal us when the value changes maybe).

Comment: If it's an element that has change events (input, textarea) you can use an event listener

Answer (score 0):

You should try the expected conditions something like this,

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value(driver.find_element_by_class_name("Cval"),"You Expected Text"))
```

Comment: This strategy is not applicable for my scenario because I do not know what the new value would be beforehand.